# PicoCli Mutually Dependent Options question (resolve values)

Tags: java, picocli

I have the following code below.

My use case is that when using option --install you must also use the option --version. This is working well when using the below Dependent group.

However I am unable to get the a value of variable version. How do i extract/resolve it?
Is there any way i can do it from the call() method?

```
@CommandLine.Command(name = "rt")
@Component
public class Artifactory implements Callable<Integer> {


    @CommandLine.ArgGroup(exclusive = false)
    Dependent dependent;

    static class Dependent{
        @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-i", "--install"}, description = "The Artifactory version")
        boolean install;

        @CommandLine.Option(names = {"-v", "--version"}, required = false, description = "The Artifactory version")
        String version;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("We are installing Artifactory version from @Artifactory: " + version);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the specified values from the `dependent` field in the `Artifactory` class. For example:

```java
@Command(name = "rt")
@Component
public class Artifactory implements Callable<Integer> {


    @ArgGroup(exclusive = false, multiplicity = "1")
    Dependent dependent;

    static class Dependent{
        @Option(names = {"-i", "--install"}, description = "Install or not.")
        boolean install;

        @Option(names = {"-v", "--version"}, required = false,
          description = "The Artifactory version.")
        String version;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        // I made the arg-group multiplicity=1, so it cannot be `null`.
        // The default is `multiplicity = "0..1"`;
        // in that case you need to check that dependent != null (if the group was not specified).
        System.out.printf(
                "We are %sinstalling Artifactory version %s%n",
                (dependent.install ? "" : "not "), dependent.version);

        return 0;
    }
}
```